# Obtain SIB1 messages from CPRI the captured DL IQ data

Tags: frequency-spectrum, signal-detection, lte

I am a beginner in the signal processing, and I know some python and I have a project I'm working on which is about Obtaining SIB1 messages from CPRI the captured DL IQ data.

I have captured some DL IQ data from CPRI Prob between the LTE BBU & RRU, and I'm interested in decoding the messages and get some basic info, like band information, or band indicator, just to know which band this AxC is related to.

For example, If the CPRI link has 8 AxC, antenna carriers, for two bands, B1 has 4 AxC, and the other second band has the remaining 4 AxCs.==> I'm interested in decoding the SIB1 messages from this captured DL IQ data so I can know which AxC is belong to which band.

The captured data coming in two csv files: (each band in one seperate file).
Both files contain IQ data from 4 antennas on each band. Each column in a file belongs to one antenna. 
There are 308736 samples for each antenna
Sample rate is 15.36 Megasamples/second.

From my research today, I found some provided answers recommending GNU Radio for such project, so it will be appreciated if any one of you can provide a feedback, advise, or recommendation, and make my day easier:

1. How to go from IQ to SIB1 messages.
2. Is GNU Radio simulation is the best to be learned/used or some other python packages can help.
3. At the end I want my CPRI prob know this automatically, instead of manual download the csv capture and analyse to see which AxC antenna related to which band.

[One document I found about GNU Radio simulation: A LTE Receiver Framework Implementation in
GNU Radio](https://www.cel.kit.edu/download/SDR-WInnComm-Europe-2013_DemelKoslowskiJondral.pdf)

Comment: Wow, MS/s data in CSV files ... the least useful format I could think of :) That's got to be a lot of data on your hard drive! So, convert your IQ CSV to a file format [that GNU Radio understands](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/FAQ#What_is_the_file_format_of_a_file_sink.3F_How_can_I_read_files_produced_by_a_file_sink.3F).

Comment: Thanks Marcus. appreciated feedback.

Comment: The .csv format is a demo, provided to me just for experiment.
Real application (production one) will be dealing with the real IQ data/streaming over the CPRI link.
So you think GNU is good for doing this job, also for the production one?! Please advise.

Comment: That's a question that asks for an opinion, not something that really has an answer. I'm kind of affiliated with GNU Radio, so you won't be getting an objective answer from me – not that your question *has* an objective answer without knowing all your skills. So, maybe just start using it? https://tutorials.gnuradio.org.

Comment: Yes Marcus, I just started learning GNU Radio.
With GNU Radio been used for this, what could summarize the steps that need to be done with the GNU to do/accomplish this project. 

Appreciate your mentoring advise on this in advance.

Comment: The steps would be summarized as "you use GNU Radio to implement your thing"; you'll notice that your question is kind of a complex, overly broad one for a comment here.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, understood.